# Adding an option to a select does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, browser

### Problem

If you add an option to a select via JavaScript subsequently everything seems to be good.

But if you have a form which is filled via database e.g. and an option from that select is preselected Internet Explorer fails: It's always the next option that is preselected.

All other browsers work fine.

### Example

Here is a working example:

```js
var oSelect = document.getElementById('myselect');
var oOption = document.createElement('option');
oOption.text = '- - - my fabulous new option - - -';
oSelect.add(oOption, oSelect[3]);
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="Algeria,DZA">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa,ASM">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra,AND">Andorra</option>
  <option selected value="Angola,AGO">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla,AIA">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Antarctica,ATA">Antarctica</option>
</select>
```

### JSFiddle

And here it's on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8k2hz26/1/).

### Question

Do you have any idea why IE reacts differently here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is introduced by the insertion of "your fabulous new option". ;)

If you insert it as 5th entry `(oSelect[4])` IE keeps html's selected value `"Angola,AGO"` selected. Yet adding something before this entry messes things up. The problem being that it will select `entry [3]` without checking if `"Angola,AGO"` still holds that position.

### Edit / Workaround

Selecting via JScript does work with IE, too. Lo, the extra <3 it always needs.

```js
var oSelect = document.getElementById('myselect');
var oOption = document.createElement('option');
oOption.text = '- - - my fabulous new option - - -';
oSelect.add(oOption, oSelect[3]);

// oSelect.value = "Angola,AGO";  <-- changed because of comments
oSelect.value = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="Algeria,DZA">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa,ASM">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra,AND">Andorra</option>
  <option selected value="Angola,AGO">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla,AIA">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Antarctica,ATA">Antarctica</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see. Thank you.
The next point is I've got no influence to the select; comes directly from a CMS. So I have to detect which option is selected before adding "my fabulous new option". But this should work ;)

Comment: sure you found out already - but for future reference, it's: `oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value;` :)

Comment: Already implemented. Works fine. Nice workaround, thanks for the advice. :)